# SQL Server 2008 - accumulating column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, accumulate

I would like to accumulate my data as you can see below there is origin table `table1`:

1. What is the best query for to do this?
2. Is possible to do this dynamically - when I add more types of terms??

Table 1

```
ID  |  term  |  value
-----------------------
1   |   I    |   100
2   |   I    |   200
3   |   II   |   100
4   |   II   |    50 
5   |   II   |    75
6   |   III  |    50
7   |   III  |    65
8   |   IV   |    30
9   |   IV   |    45
```

And the result should be like below:

```
YTD  | Acc Value
------------------
I-I  |   300
I-II |   525
I-III|   640
I-IV |   715
```

Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Specify your sql server version. In >2008 windowed functions had been introduced that would be useful in this task, whereas in <=2008 versions you have to sweat a little bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    select 
        (select min(term) from yourtable ) +'-'+term,       
        (select sum(value) from yourtable  t1 where t1.term<=t.term)
    from yourtable t 
    group by term
```